# Does FreeBSD have problems using ext2fs with external USB hard drives that have a sector size of 4096 Bytes?

Tags: linux, mount, freebsd, usb-drive, ext2

I have two identical 1TB external USB-disks which I have formatted under Linux using `ext2fs`. If I run `lsusb` in Linux I get the lines:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc.
```

Both drives have one partition taking up the whole disk. When I boot into FreeBSD, the two drives are reported as `/dev/da0` and `/dev/da1`, with partitions `/dev/da0s1` and `/dev/da1s1`. I can mount `/dev/da0s1` without a problem with:

```
mount -t ext2fs /dev/da0s1 <path>
```

but when I want to mount the second drive with

```
mount -t ext2fs /dev/da1s1 <path>
```

I get the message

```
mount: /dev/da1s1: Invalid argument
```

I do not know if it can help, here is the output of `gpart list` for the two disks:

```
Geom name: da0
modified: false
state: OK
fwheads: 255
fwsectors: 63
last: 1953525167
first: 63
entries: 4
scheme: MBR
Providers:
1. Name: da0s1
   Mediasize: 1000201224704 (932G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r1w1e1
   rawtype: 131
   length: 1000201224704
   offset: 1048576
   type: linux-data
   index: 1
   end: 1953520064
   start: 2048
Consumers:
1. Name: da0
   Mediasize: 1000204886016 (932G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r1w1e2
```

and

```
Geom name: da1
modified: false
state: OK
fwheads: 255
fwsectors: 63
last: 244190645
first: 63
entries: 4
scheme: MBR
Providers:
1. Name: da1s1
   Mediasize: 1000193654784 (932G)
   Sectorsize: 4096
   Stripesize: 0
   Stripeoffset: 262144
   Mode: r0w0e0
   attrib: active
   rawtype: 131
   length: 1000193654784
   offset: 262144
   type: linux-data
   index: 1
   end: 244187967
   start: 64
Consumers:
1. Name: da1
   Mediasize: 1000204886016 (932G)
   Sectorsize: 4096
   Mode: r0w0e0
```

**EDIT**

I tried removing the good disk and rebooting. Now the bad disk is detected as `/dev/da0`. Here is the output of `dmesg`:

```
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus6 target 0 lun 0
da0: <Intenso USB 3.0 device 0> Fixed Direct Access SPC-4 SCSI device
da0: Serial Number 30100000000000000263
da0: 400.000MB/s transfers
da0: 953869MB (244190646 4096 byte sectors)
da0: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
```

and mounting it fails:

```
# mount -t ext2fs /dev/da0s1 mnt0
mount: /dev/da0s1: Invalid argument
```

With two disks, the output of `dmesg` is:

```
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus6 target 0 lun 0
da0: <Intenso USB 3.0 Device 0> Fixed Direct Access SPC-4 SCSI device
da0: Serial Number 30700000000000001682
da0: 400.000MB/s transfers
da0: 953869MB (1953525168 512 byte sectors)
da0: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
...
da1 at umass-sim1 bus 1 scbus7 target 0 lun 0
da1: <Intenso USB 3.0 device 0> Fixed Direct Access SPC-4 SCSI device
da1: Serial Number 30100000000000000263
da1: 400.000MB/s transfers
da1: 953869MB (244190646 4096 byte sectors)
da1: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
...
```

The bad disk uses 4096-byte sectors while the good one uses 512-byte sectors. Can the sector size be the problem?

**NOTE**

I have not been able to solve this problem. I finally decided to format both disks with UFS, attach them to a FreeBSD Raspberrypi, and make them available to other computers via the network.

Comment: Did you try use only the "bad" disk? In this case it will be `/dev/da0`. Did you see output of `dmesg`?

Comment: What does the `Mode: r0w0e0` mean in the gpart geom output? My guess is read off, write off. So that's maybe your problem.

Comment: @wurtel: You mean read and write are disabled? I cannot find any complete documentation on the output of `gpart geom` so I do not know how to interpret the `Mode` field.

Comment: Yes, sector size in conjunction with (bad) partition alignment can be the problem.

Comment: @dirkt: However, it works without any problems under Linux. In any case, should I repartition the disk? Is it possible to change the sector size using a partitioning tool?

Comment: What puzzles me is that both disks are the same model, bought at a few months distance. Why do they have different physical block sizes?

Comment: Also, while I'm not familiar with BSD and `gpart`, what irritates me is the different and non-zero `stripesize` and `stripeoffset`. Is it possible that both drives are mounted as part of a single RAID?

Comment: @dirkt: If this were the case, the problem should disappear when I remove the good drive (?) Anyway, running `gpart list` with only the bad drive attached gives the same result for `stripesize` and `stripeoffset`.

Comment: I had a similar problem (i.e. block size mismatch) once which had the origin of using the disk in an external enclosure: Some of these (e.g. USB3 HDD case) will map the drive from/to 512/4096 block size. I solved the problem by taking the risk (!) of deleting and re-creating the partition table by searching for the start sectors using the other unit (don't remember which way around it was). The FS and data was still there and intact. Could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: I bought the disks with a built-in enclosure and I plug them directly on my computer using a USB cable. So there is nothing but the USB cable between the disks and my computer. Repartitioning the disks is not a problem: I am backing up my data right now, should be finished in one hour or so. I want to try using 512 logical sectors since, as far as I understand, it is not possible to change the physical sector size, because that is determined by the controller.

Comment: @Giorgio "There is nothing but the USB cable..": This is not really true. The disk is most probably a SATA disk, and there is an electronics board with firmware which bridges/translates between USB and SATA. This is where the changeover of logical unit size can take place (and it did in my case).  Once removed from the enclosure I needed to fix the partition table accordingly, which carries a risk.  -- Are the 2 disks (+enclosures) identical? Has any one of them been taken out of the enclosure? Is it possible it "changed" the allocation size at that moment?

Comment: @Ned64: The enclosures are identical and both disks are sold by the same company as 1T external drives. However, I found out that internally two different disks are used, even the vendors are different. I made further experiments and have posted a question on the FreeBSD forum (https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/58489/).

Comment: OK, so the question could be: Does FreeBSD have problems with external USB hard drives that have a sector size of 4096 Bytes?

Comment: @Ned64: More precisely: Does FreeBSD have problems using ext2fs with external USB hard drives that have a sector size of 4096 Bytes? I tested ufs on this drive and it seems to work OK.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sadly, I do not know it :-(  It is, however, good, to have a precise question (for the FreeBSD developers, I suppose?!).

Comment: FreeBSD itself can apparently handle the blocksize: http://bxr.su/s?refs=e2fs_bsize&project=FreeBSD  and https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/fs/ext2fs/ext2fs.h?revision=303800&view=markup#l323

Comment: @Ned64: Thanks for all the feedback. I have considered compiling the package from source and possibly inserting a few printfs to debug it.

Comment: This could also help (unless this is you): http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=9572

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48422/discussion-between-giorgio-and-ned64).